# I want to add A-Z filter on my .cshtml page. Any one can help me to add that?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to add A-Z filter on my cshtml page. Any one can help me to add that?

I want Index page. And any one click on A then then control goes to A with query string.

Comment: Could you please explain your question a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
<ul>
@for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++)
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(((char) i).ToString(), "Index","Home", new {query = (char) i}, null) </li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank You. And I want also Filter Like A-Z and All with this. So can you help me?

Comment: Just add <li>@Html.ActionLink("All", "Index","Home", new {query = "All"}, null) </li> below the cycle code block